# opc server written in java makes my java UI stop working

Tags: user-interface, opc, jnetpcap

I have created a user interface in java which uses card layout. It basically shows a lot of readings in it which it receives through our company's local network. Now I had to write an OPC server in java so that all the readings my ui receives is stored onto that server. I successfully wrote it. My UI works awesome for almost a day but the next day when i come to office, I find my UI frozen, as in there is no more communication taking place. The UI stops receiving or transmitting numbers. When i run the UI without OPC, it goes on and on forever but its when i add OPC to it, that it freezes/ I have tried all sorts of stuff but I still have not been able to solve it. ANd yes, I have used Jnet Pcap to capture the packets in the UI. There is a huge amount of code in it so if anyone requires any specific code to look at, let me know.

Answer (score -2):

This is really hard to follow. What is the exact problem that you are facing is still unclear.
The openSCADA website that has the free OPC implementation should be your best bet...
http://openscada.org/projects/utgard/

More over you can try the JEasyOPC client which is also free incipiently.